# Using SQL Server Management Studio. Pulling terms that are not 'active' within the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query was created to show projected fees - which is why I converted terms to cost - as shown below. I only wanted the terms I outlined within the query to show, but I wanted them to be active terms within the database. I am at a loss on how to make this happen because the results are showing the correct term numbers/cost, but older inactive matters.

**CURRENT QUERY:**

```
SELECT distinct 
   Team_Effort.LOGIN_ID AS [Attorney] 
   ,DATENAME(MONTH, e.Term_DATE) AS [Month]
   ,Convert (CHAR, e.TERM_DATE, 110) AS [Due Date]
   ,PAT_CASE.OLD_CASE_ID AS [Case Number]
   ,CASE 
                    WHEN Event_text.EVENT_TEXT_STATUS IS NULL
                                THEN est.EVENT_SCHEME_TEXT
                    ELSE Event_text.EVENT_TEXT_STATUS
   END AS [Status Text]
   ,CASE 
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '1'  
                                 THEN '5500'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '110'  
                                 THEN '5500'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '210'  
                                 THEN '1000'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '270'  
                                 THEN '1000'            
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '500' 
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '1440'  
                                 THEN '3050'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62145'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62285'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8200'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8300'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10000'  
                                 THEN '2000'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10200'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10300'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10400'  
                                 THEN '300'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10500'  
                                 THEN '2900'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10700'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10900'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '11100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '12100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '12150'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60045'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60100'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60150'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60585'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60750'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60830'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61185'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61320'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61460'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62545'  
                                 THEN '2900'
                    ELSE E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID 
   END AS [Cost]                   
FROM PAT_CASE
```

Comment: What is your question, what is the criteria for active?

Comment: I think you need to reword the question. You talk about "converting terms to costs" but the query is talking about EVENT_SCHEME_ID, there is nothing pointing to these being active or not, etc etc.

Comment: Term is equal to e.event_scheme_id. And I used the below when/then statement below to convert the term to cost.

Comment: You have no where clause, which would be the place to filter out inactive based on...?

Comment: Sorry, that sent to quickly. Term is equal to e.event_scheme_id. And I used the following when/then statement to convert term to cost: when e.event_scheme_id = '60750' then '1800.' The results that are being returned are the terms I put in the query - i.e. 60100, 601050, 60585, etc. but the results are pulling active and inactive data from the database. I don't know what command to use to only pull active data from the database. Please let me know if this is still unclear. My apologies.

Comment: How do you decide what is active?

Comment: Please see full query below - the where clause is toward the end.

Comment: I decide what is active by looking in the database itself and seeing what terms are still showing on a particular case and have not been closed out.

Comment: You did not post the whole query, it ends with `FROM PAT_CASE`

Comment: WHERE e.TERM_DATE = (
                        SELECT max(EVENT.TERM_DATE)
                        FROM event
                        WHERE event.CASE_ID = pat_case.case_id
                                    AND event.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID
                        )

Comment: I will repost/reword my question. The full query will not fit within a comment box. Thank you everyone for your attempted help.

Comment: you need t find the open ones only in the where clause. How can you tell if a term has been "Closed"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform aggregate functions in a `WHERE` clause.  Try creating a calculated column called [IsActive] using that criteria.  It'll help clean up your code as well.

```
SELECT distinct 
   [Attorney] = Team_Effort.LOGIN_ID 
   ,[Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, e.Term_DATE)
   ,[Due Date] = Convert (CHAR, e.TERM_DATE, 110)
   ,[Case Number] = PAT_CASE.OLD_CASE_ID
   ,[Status Text] = CASE 
                      WHEN Event_text.EVENT_TEXT_STATUS IS NULL
                                THEN est.EVENT_SCHEME_TEXT
                      ELSE Event_text.EVENT_TEXT_STATUS
                    END
   ,[IsActive] = CASE
                    WHEN e.TERM_DATE = ( SELECT max(EVENT.TERM_DATE) FROM event WHERE event.CASE_ID = pat_case.case_id AND event.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID )
                                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
                 END

   ,[Cost] = CASE 
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '1'  
                                 THEN '5500'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '110'  
                                 THEN '5500'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '210'  
                                 THEN '1000'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '270'  
                                 THEN '1000'            
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '500' 
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '1440'  
                                 THEN '3050'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62145'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62285'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8200'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '8300'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10000'  
                                 THEN '2000'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10200'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10300'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10400'  
                                 THEN '300'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10500'  
                                 THEN '2900'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10700'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '10900'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '11100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '12100'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '12150'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60045'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60100'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60150'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60585'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60750'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '60830'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61185'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61320'  
                                 THEN '1800'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '61460'  
                                 THEN '400'
                    WHEN E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID = '62545'  
                                 THEN '2900'
                    ELSE E.EVENT_SCHEME_ID 
         END                   
FROM PAT_CASE
WHERE [ISActive] = 1
```